# Magento 2.3.2: Error when attempting to install new theme

Tags: magento, magento2

I'm trying to create a new theme based on Luma.

After I run:

```
    php bin/magento setup:upgrade
```

I run:

```
    php -dmemory_limit=5G bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f
```

and I get the following error:

```
    In File.php line 151:

      The contents from the 
     "/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/magento2/pub/static/frontend/Guidance  
      /m2-theme/en_US/mage/translate-inline-vde.css" file can't be read. 

    Warning! file_get_contents(/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/magento2/pub/static/frontend/Guidance/m2-theme/en_US/mage/translate-inline-vde.css): failed to open stream: No such file or directory
```

It looks like I'm missing some necessary files. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It looks like you did not give permission to pub folder.

Please try below command:

```
chmod -R 777 pub/ var/ generated/
```

Note: In case of Ubuntu OS only.

Comment: 777 is a security risk.

Comment: Please read this: https://www.mageants.com/blog/guide-of-magento-2-file-and-folder-permissions.html
It is not security risk to give permission to these folders. Or please provide me doc I would love to read. Also, this answer is related to local only.

Comment: It is a security risk because if you host your project on shared hosting others could easily change your files or add their own. They could also just delete your var/ pub/ and generated/ folder.